# How to circumvent "This file does not belong to any project target"?

Tags: cmake, include, clion, directory-structure

I'm using CLion (2022.2 EAP).

I have some source files in my CMake C/C++ project directory structure which - for now - are not mentioned in the CMakeLists.txt ; they probably never will. But - I want them to be parsed with certain include directories to search includes in. Can I do this without adding them as proper targets?

Comment: You could create a dummy target which lists the files. Otherwise, unfortunately, CLion will not "see" these files as part of your project.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Do you mean an `add_custom_target()`? If not, can you be more specific? Anyway, that sounds like an answer.

Comment: That might work, but I was thinking more like a library target. If nothing depends on the library it won't be built, but the source files for the target will still be part of the project.

Comment: " If nothing depends on the library it won't be built" <- Don't think that's true, but I could use [`EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html) I suppose.

Comment: Indeed, you can create some dummy target with `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, so that it won't be built.